# What is required to get the roll, pitch and yaw of an aerial vehicle?

Tags: imu, gyroscope, accelerometer

TL, DR : What is the method(in terms of sensors and algorithm) to get the roll, pitch and yaw of an aircraft at any instant.

I am planning to build a hobby aircraft. I am so confused about which kind of sensors should I use and how to use them in order to get the roll, pitch and yaw angles of the aircraft.

I think I also have some problems about understanding the concept.

What are the ways/methods/agents to get the orientation of an aircraft at any instant?

In some sources there is something going on as the importance of order of the application of roll,pitch and yaw. But I cannot understand why this is related.

I have used accelerometer values by inputting them into some formulas on the internet(which everybody uses but nobody explains well) to get the roll and pitch values. However could not understand how to manipulate them in order to meet my requirements.

I also have basic understanding about what a gyroscope is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "some formulas on the internet(which everybody uses but nobody explains well) to get the roll and pitch values" I would start at trying to understand those formula's. Can you put up those formula's here with the question?

Comment: @vvy yes I know but I realy am bad at 3d geometric imagination. Do you have any suggestions that I can use to visualize such vectors/axes ?

Comment: The question you've asked is very general. Its a good idea to start with a smaller question. Usually, gyro rate sensors are used for RPY(rate,pitch,yaw). Might be helpful to understand what is a **raw output** of a gyro and then the transformation to obtain the quantity of interest (here it's RPY). Those equations you're referring to would probably explain this transformation.

Comment: @vvy I am more clear about gyro calculations than accelemoter actualy, I know as follows(please revise and give me feedback about it) : gyro measures the rotation speed about an axis, so we can get the gyro readings(**dps**) over a short time(**dt**) duration and add to the p/r/y variable as dps*dt - an approximation of integartion -. So by this, with respect to an inital attitude we can have a relative p,r,y angles. But this has two disadvantages, the drift issue(errors cumulatively increases because of integration) and the problem mentioned here : https://youtu.be/4BoIE8YQwM8?t=596

Comment: @vvy so I am not a total stranger, have the basics somehow but need to relate each of them.

Comment: As I understand, you want to eliminate orientation drift. With gyro alone this might not be possible. With an added accelerometer you can calculate the gravity vector and check drift in two of the axes and with a magnetometer you can check the drift about the remaining axis. I think, if you reword your question, you will attract great answers.

Comment: @vvy yes but again by my readings I learned that in a moving system(accelerating) accelerator values are no longer reliable, which is not suprising indeed. So yes my question is on a bit wider topic but this is the best way of describing my desire. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

The only sustainable long-term acceleration (for anything terrestrial) is gravity. The [Madgwick algorithm](https://x-io.co.uk/open-source-imu-and-ahrs-algorithms/) uses gravity and a magnetometer to correct gyro drift.

[Watch the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BXsGWoOMtmU), then head to the site - there are open-source implementations already written for you in Matlab, C, and C#.

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look at the links you shared. Could you please somehow describe what you wanted to mean by "terrestrial"? I am not a native speaker and that word is hard to understand for me.

Comment: @muyustan - Basically rockets. I think it's easiest to think of the Madgwick filter as a low-pass filter on the accelerometer: over the long-term (very low frequency), the *average* of your accelerometer readings should be only the gravity vector, and you know it points down. The exception is if you were able to maintain an acceleration for a long period of time, such as ballistic missiles, or in unusual applications like a centrifuge or something similar. But for quadcopters, vehicles, etc., your average acceleration is only gravity. You can see the effect when the IMU converges in the video.

Answer (score 0):

Use mpu6050 gyroscope module and optional compass module to know where is the North. Mpu6050 can be calibrated by itself, but you have to write a code that calibrates readings with mpu6050's accelerometer sensor(using atan2 function)